# Android Getting a Set from SharedPrefs is corrupting the order

Tags: android, list, set, sharedpreferences

I have a method like this:

```
public static void setSearchHistory(Activity activity, int channelId) {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(activity);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = sp.edit();

    Set<String> searchHistory = sp.getStringSet("searchHistory", new LinkedHashSet<String>());
    List<String> shList = new ArrayList<>();
    shList.addAll(searchHistory);

    if(shList.size() > 0) {
        boolean wasAdded = false;
        for(int i=0;i<shList.size();i++) {
            Integer channelID = Integer.parseInt(shList.get(i));
            if(channelId == channelID) {
                shList.remove(i);
                shList.add(0, String.valueOf(channelId));
                wasAdded = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!wasAdded) {
            shList.add(0, String.valueOf(channelId));
        }
    } else {
        shList.add(String.valueOf(channelId));
    }

    if(shList.size() > 10) {
        for(int i=10;i<shList.size();i++) {
            shList.remove(i);
        }
    }

    searchHistory = new LinkedHashSet<>(shList);

    prefsEditor.putStringSet("searchHistory", searchHistory);
    prefsEditor.apply();
}
```

This method does get `channelId` param and add it in the first position of the `Set` and save back to `SharedPreferences`. It also controls if `channelId` is already in the list. If so, it removes `channelId` from current position and adds it in the first position. Then it removes last items until its size is 10.

I put the `List` back to `Set`, the order of the list is right. I also took screenshot for them:

The `Set` after the `List` added to it:
[image]

But when I get the `Set` back from `SharedPreferences` like below, the order of the list is mixed-up very randomly.

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(activity);

Set<String> searchHistory = sp.getStringSet("searchHistory", new LinkedHashSet<String>());
List<String> shList = new ArrayList<>();
shList.addAll(searchHistory);
```

The `Set` after saved to `SharedPreferences`:
[image]

This is really annoying, I don't want it to mix up the order. :(

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are aware that a `Set` does not guarantee an order?

Comment: That's why I use `LinkedHashSet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround from another question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18836862/778246)

I totally removed `Set`objects and replace them with `JSONArray` saving into SharedPrefs just `String` as follows;

Putting `List` into SharedPrefs:

```
public static void setSearchHistory(Activity activity, int channelId) {
    try {
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(activity);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = sp.edit();

        JSONArray searchHistory;
        List<String> shList = new ArrayList<>();
        if(sp.getString("searchHistory", null) != null) {
            searchHistory = new JSONArray(sp.getString("searchHistory", null));
            for(int i=0;i<searchHistory.length();i++) {
                shList.add(searchHistory.get(i).toString());
            }
        }

        if(shList.size() > 0) {
            boolean wasAdded = false;
            for(int i=0;i<shList.size();i++) {
                Integer channelID = Integer.parseInt(shList.get(i));
                if(channelId == channelID) {
                    shList.remove(i);
                    shList.add(0, String.valueOf(channelId));
                    wasAdded = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!wasAdded) {
                shList.add(0, String.valueOf(channelId));
            }
        } else {
            shList.add(String.valueOf(channelId));
        }

        if(shList.size() > 10) {
            for(int i=10;i<shList.size();i++) {
                shList.remove(i);
            }
        }

        searchHistory = new JSONArray(shList);

        prefsEditor.putString("searchHistory", searchHistory.toString());
        prefsEditor.apply();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And getting `List` from SharedPrefs:

```
public static List<Channel> getSearchHistory(Activity activity) {
    try {
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(activity);

        List<String> shList = new ArrayList<>();
        if(sp.getString("searchHistory", null) != null) {
            JSONArray searchHistory = new JSONArray(sp.getString("searchHistory", null));
            for(int i=0;i<searchHistory.length();i++) {
                shList.add(searchHistory.get(i).toString());
            }
        }

        List<Channel> channelList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<shList.size();i++) {
            Channel channel = Channel.findChannelByID(Integer.parseInt(shList.get(i)), activity);
            channelList.add(channel);
        }

        return channelList;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Works like a charm. Yay!